Show f an isometry with a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a composition of 1 or 2 reflections

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be an isometry with a fixed point $A \in \mathbb{R}^2$. That is, $f(A) = A$. Show that $f$ is a composition of $1$ or $2$ reflections.

Here is my attempt. I would appreciate feedbacks on its correctness and completeness, and also other more concise proofs as well. Thank you.
Edit: Assuming a Euclidean plane. Some other results I can think of and use are

Let $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be three non collinear points. Then $\forall p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is uniquely determined by its distance from $A,B,C$. This result is proved by a a simple contradiction proof.
Three point determination theorem: An isometry $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is determined by its image $f(A), f(B), f(C)$ of $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}^2$ not collinear. The proof of this uses the previous result.

Attempt:
Using three point determination theorem, let $A,B,C$ be three points not collinear. We want to find reflections which sends $A$ to $f(A)$, $B$ to $f(B)$, and $C$ to $f(C)$.
Since $A$ is fixed, nothing needs to be done for this point. We can send $B$ to $f(B)$ by reflection in the equidistance line of $B$ and $f(B)$ and call this reflection $r_B$.
Now $r_B$ sends $C$ to $r_B(C)$. So if $r_B(C) = f(C)$, then we do nothing. We can then conclude that $f$ is an isometry of $1$ reflection. Otherwise, if $r_B(C) \ne f(C)$, we can send $r_B(C)$ to $f(C)$ by a reflection in the equidistant line of $r_B(C)$ and $f(C)$ and call this reflection $r_C$. We can then conclude that $f$ is an isometry of two reflections.
Edited 2: We now show why (1) $A$ is unchanged under $r_B$ and (2) $A,B$ is unchanged under $r_C$.

By definition $r_B(B) = f(B)$. We want to show $r_B(f(A)) = f(A)$. It suffices to show that $A=f(A)$ is on the equidistant line between $B$ and $f(B)$, call it $L_B$ (since if this is the case, reflecting a point across a line through itself will definitely not change the location of this point). Since $f$ is isometry, $|f(A)f(B)| = |AB| = |Af(B)|$. The latter half of the equality shows $A=f(A) \in L_B$.
This proof is similar to the one above. Except replace $r_B$ with $r_C$ and perform this on the points $A,B$.

Hence, any isometry is a composition of $r_B$ and $r_C$.

It might help to edit the question to mention any results you have available. For example, it seems you're assuming a Euclidean plane isometry with three non-collinear fixed points is the identity.

As the theorems available for you to apply get more powerful, the proofs get more concise. For example, here's a very concise proof, based on a classification theorem which says that every isometry is a reflection, glide reflector, rotation, translation, or the identity. From that theorem it follows that the only isometries having a fixed point are rotations, reflections, and the identity. Every rotation is a composition of 2 reflections, and so is the identity.

@AndrewD.Hwang I've edited the question a little and provided the relevant theorems we were given that I can think of might be useful. Thanks for feedback.

@LeeMosher I see, maybe I will see that result later on in the book. In my context, we weren't really given that much to work with. Only the two theorems I've listed.

I think you should explain, in your proof, why $A$ is a fixed point of $r_B$ and why both $A$ and $B$ are fixed points of $r_C$.

@Intelligentipauca Thanks! I've edited the proof. Please take a look and see if you think it makes sense or have anything to add.
